# Can't Modify Imported Font from FontAwesome

Tags: css

I am unable to edit [this font](https://fontawesome.com/icons/child?style=solid) from FontAwesome. When I add `<i class="fas fa fa-child"></i>` to my code I can see the child figure. But when I added this to my CSS:

```
.fa {
    background-color: green;
    color: red;
}
```

But, nothing happened to the child icon. I know this is something little but I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Comment: Is your css (in the header) behind or before the font-awesome css? (This can make a difference)

Comment: @LuisM. thats not true...

Comment: Before, so i tried to change it but nothing happend.

Comment: @Durinko could you show us a working example so we can solve you issue because as I have tested it its working fine

Comment: @Bhuwan But it can make a difference. If the font awesome css contains a color:inehrit; the own css gets overwritten when writing it in front of the font-awesome css

Comment: The icon is an svg...?

Comment: To be honest i just used fontawesome and i have no idea what is it.

Comment: Did you use `<i class="fas fa-child"></i>` ?

Comment: Yes and added fa to class

Comment: @Durinko you are using font-awesome5 which is `svg` based. So you cant set the background-color and color to `svg`.....you can use svg fill property. Your code will work if you use font-awesome4

Comment: @Durinko Your code will work if you use [**font-awesome4**](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

Comment: Thanks @BhuwanBhatt i didnt realize it :)

Comment: I can set a color. i use pure CSS Font-Awesome 5 `<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontAwesome5 that you are using is SVG based, so u need to edit it like SVG.
Visit - https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/